# How do you install Pantheon on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, pantheon

Has anyone managed to install Pantheon on Ubuntu 16.04? The dock shows up for me but not the applications menu or indicators. Thanks!

Comment: Note: For me, Dock, app menu and indicators show up, but I can't type to search in the app menu.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju You could make that an answer. There's a bounty to be had.  You can mention which flavor you installed it on and which version.

Comment: @Fiksdal Ah, didn't consider the bounty aspect. Posting.

Answer (score 21):

**Edit: I installed Pantheon on Ubuntu 16.04 a week ago and it has been working fine so far. Though it does freeze up sometimes for a second or two right after I log-in. (Then again, Pantheon wasn't designed and isn't technically compatible for Ubuntu). But other than that, it is working just fine. This is how I installed it:**

To install the Panteon desktop on Ubuntu go to the terminal and type, (These are packages from daily and testing PPAs):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop
```

To install the latest elementary-tweaks:

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-dev libpolkit-gobject-1-dev
git clone https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks
cd elementary-tweaks
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ../
make
sudo make install
```

// run

```
switchboard
```

To install Pantheon desktop on Ubuntu from the official Elementary OS PPA, type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

There you go! Reboot and select Pantheon as your desktop on the login screen!

Comment: This question isn't about how to install Pantheon, it is whether anyone has tried it and how well it works.

Comment: Sorry about that. Though I did try Pantheon on a Ubuntu 16.04 PC about a week ago and it's working just fine. I just added that to my answer.

Comment: Cool, I've changed my downvote to an upvote. So, you didn't have a single problem? Please add more details if you can.

Comment: Not really. Though it does freeze up sometimes right after I log-in. (Then again, Pantheon wasn't designed and isn't technically compatible for Ubuntu). But other than that, it is working just fine.

Comment: OK, you can add that to your answer.

Comment: I've just added it. :)

Comment: Thanks :) How long did the freeze last? Did you have to hard reboot?

Comment: About a second or two.

Comment: Oh that's no big deal.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Ubuntu looks like crap and Elementary OS added a new grub entry even though it wasn't installed independently. If you're coming here from google avoid this answer. Neither the first or second solution work. Additionally, when running  cmake under the `tweaks` section there are over 6 dependencies missing and cmake fails on a fresh 16.04.1 install.

Answer (score 4):

System: Xubuntu 16.04

DE: Xfce (GNOME is also installed)

Installed: `pantheon` package from `ppa:elementaryos/daily`

Results: Nearly fine, but

- Icons in top bar look too big
- Menus in top bar have widgets that look too big
- Cannot type to search in app menu (Slingshot)
- Some icons are themed with the icon theme selected in GNOME (Numix circle) but rest are unthemed.

Comment: Big difference between the two answers. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Fiksdal Most likely because @TheChosenOne99: 1) installed the full `elementary-desktop` package (I just installed `pantheon`) and 2) enabled the `elementary-os/os-patches` repo.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 answers left me hanging. Here are the only installation commands you need to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install pantheon-files
```

Then the *only* way that I could actually find the app was to go into the **Applications** overlay and search for **Files**. Note that I also have **Nautilus** installed (which I was using before) and it also shows up as **Files**. I had to figure out which was which and add the one corresponding to **Pantheon Files** to my favorites. Now I don't need to look for it anymore!

I got the commands from: https://codeyarns.com/2013/06/03/how-to-install-pantheon-files-on-ubuntu/