# How to remove Pantheon DE from Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, 16.04, uninstall, elementary, pantheon

Can anyone help me remove `elementary-desktop`? I installed it in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 system. I already did the "solution" from this question:
[How to completely remove Elementary-Desktop from Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631023/how-to-completely-remove-elementary-desktop-from-ubuntu-14-04)
and also

```
sudo apt-get purge elementary-desktop elementary-icon-theme elementary-theme elementary-default-settings
```

still no luck. I also did

```
sudo apt-get autoclean elementary-desktop
```

still didn't do the job. It's still in my system, "elementary OS Desktop" is written in my bar, plus it could still be selected during login.

[image]

Btw, I just followed the installation here: [How do you install Pantheon on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766673/pantheon-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I already tried using `synaptic`, still no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used `dist-upgrade` to install Elementary DE. By doing so, you installed PPA provided versions of packages over standard Ubuntu versions. For example, if Ubuntu provides a `nautilus` package, and those PPAs provide another `nautilus` package with higher version, you installed that one.

That's why only removing extra elementary packages such as `elementary-desktop`, `elementary-icon-themes` is not sufficient. You have to remove those patched packages too!

So, to completely remove elementary *effect*, you must go back to Ubuntu versions of packages. To do so, you need `ppa-purge`. Because only (as a tool to do these things) `ppa-purge` downgrade packages from PPA versions to Ubuntu versions.

Use these (Change the list according to your usage of PPAs)

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

To completely get rid of elementary things.

If you don't have `ppa-purge` already installed, install using

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

---

**Note 1:** If you already removed those PPA repository either using `sudo apt-add-repository -r` or manually editing files, re-add them. Because `ppa-purge` needs those package list to do the downgrading. After re-adding them, use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

command to refresh package index.

**Note 2:** If you are having an error from `ppa-purge` saying it can't find `aptitude` use

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

to install it.

**Note 3:** If `ppa-purge` fails for some PPAs not being available, remove those PPA entries manually. `ppa-purge` won't work if every repository doesn't work.

**Note 4:** If some of PPAs are disabled now (after installing package from them), you have little luck downgrading them automatically. You can identify them and manually downgrade them using synaptic or aptitude. But it's a tedious job.

**Note 5:** If you still see Elementary session listed on Lightdm, remove `pantheon-session` package manually.

**Notes 6:** Remove every extra packages you can identify installed from those PPAs but not available in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I already removed those PPAs, can I re-add them? So that I could `ppa-purge` them?

Comment: Yes. if you didn't use `ppa-purge` to remove those ppas, re-add them

Comment: After re-adding them, do I still need to do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: No. You should only use `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Okay, got it. I'm doing it right now.

Comment: I got this output:

`darth@darth-Inspiron7559:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason`

All through out the end

Comment: OK. some ppas seem to be removed or not available now. I don't know if you used those. anyway, continue using ppa-purge

Comment: You mean, I'll re-run the ppa-purge commands?

Comment: Yes. since some are missing PPAs. remove those ppa entry manually editing the file or removing them and do `ppa-purge` on rest of the repositories

Comment: I had this error: `/usr/sbin/ppa-purge: line 191: aptitude: command not found`

Comment: install aptitude with `sudo apt-get install aptitude`. Though, `ppa-purge` should have pulled that one already!

Comment: I did all the ppa-purge, repeatedly actually. Still, no luck.

Comment: I don't know how many PPAs actually exists after _infecting_ your machine. If those PPAs aren't exists anymore, you have no luck other than manually identifying every package not from Ubuntu repo, downgrading

Comment: Okay, good news. I successfully removed the elementary-desktop. However, there are two remnants of it: (1) it is still visible as an option in my lightdm, (2) I can't use the shortcut key for my terminal which is `Ctrl+Alt+T`

Comment: To remove the lightdm entry look for packages named `elementary-session` or such. remove. And you can re-assign shortcut for terminal

Comment: I searched for `elementary-session` via `synaptic`, it didn't find it. As for the shortcut, I have it configured to be called via `Ctrl+Alt+T`. The thing is, when I'm pressing that shortcut, the terminal is not being called.

Comment: I've deleted the pantheon session, I've read this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81161/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm

Comment: As for the shortcut, I made a custom shortcut instead of the shortcut being in  the Launcher shortcuts. Thanks very much for the help! :)

Comment: Btw, the ppa-purge was failing at first because of the `ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily`. I removed it using `synaptic` and tried ppa-purge once again (without the mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily). It got the job done. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score -1):

I just did it with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge elementary-desktop
```