# How can I unscrew my Ubuntu 16.04 after Pantheon DE screwed it up?

Tags: 16.04, elementary-theme

I wanted to try the Pantheon DE following [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766673/how-do-you-install-pantheon-on-ubuntu-16-04).
Now I have weird icons:

[image]

See the "Terminal" Mini-Icon over some window bar button.
How can this be fixed?

---

Edit per 08. May 2018:
[This instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766673/how-do-you-install-pantheon-on-ubuntu-16-04/780382#780382).

Comment: Can downvoting user please comment?

Comment: I checked the reviews and this question was reviewed by one reviewer as "unclear what you're asking" which is wrong in my opinion. My review was "Leave Open". The "I don't know = downvote/close" mentality on almost all Stack Exchange sites nowadays is sad.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't clear (at least to me). Did you mean [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/780382/225694) or [this instruction?](https://askubuntu.com/a/783042/225694) Please [edit] your post  to indicate which answer you followed. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Edited according to request to make clear.